# Formatear datos para envio Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

Estoy tratando de enviar una lista a Excel, en Razor Pages, pero quiero que esto me funcione para proximos envios, aqui lo que tengo :

```
[Keyless]
public class Excel
{
    public string Suministro { get; set; }
    public string Concepto { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
public List<Excel> Excel { get; set; }

public FileResult OnPostExcel(string codigo)
    {
        Consulta = string.Format("Exec NF_Informes @opt = 3, @Suministro = {0}, @fecha = Null", codigo);
        Excel = _contextoFile.Excel.FromSqlRaw(Consulta).ToList();

        XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook();
        workbook.AddWorksheet("File");
        IXLWorksheet ws = workbook.Worksheet("File");

        PropertyInfo[] propiedades = typeof(Excel).GetTypeInfo().GetProperties();
        int columna = 1;
        foreach(PropertyInfo propiedad in propiedades)
        {
            ws.Cell(1, columna).Value = propiedad.Name;
            columna++;
        }

        int fila = 2;
        foreach (var item in Excel)
        {
            columna = 1;
            foreach (PropertyInfo propiedad in propiedades)
            {
                ws.Cell(fila, columna).Value = // ?
                columna++;
            }
            fila++;
        }

        using (MemoryStream Stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            workbook.SaveAs(Stream);
            var data = Stream.ToArray();
            string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            return File(data, contentType, "File.xlsx");
        }
    }
```

Mi problema esta en el signo //?, no encuentro la forma de poner en dicho bucle mis valores, es decir, podria hacer lo siguiente : item.Suministro; pero como dije al inicio, yo quiero mas adelante poder reutilizar estas instrucciones.

Gracias.

Comment: Así de primeras se me ocurre usar un diccionario en la clase Excel para guardar los datos o una función tipo getvalor(string)

Comment: Probaste con propiedad.GetValue(item) ?????

Comment: Que buena Yussef! no se me habia ocurrido, solo estaba tratando de obtener el valor a partir de "item" y no desde "propiedad". Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

**Usar Reflection:**

Con reflection tomarias el *nombre* de la propiedad y usarias el GetValue() pasandole la instancia(*objeto*) de la clase para tomar el valor

```
 public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
 {
     return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
 }
```

Supongo que es poco eficiente pero si no trabajas con una gran cantidad de datos y pocas solicitudes a la vez(administración en un back office) no debería importar

ejemplo:)

```
GetPropValue(item,"Suministro")
```

es lo mismo que:

```
  item.suministro
```

Solución:

```
public class FilaExcel
{
    public string? Suministro { get; set; }
    public string? Concepto { get; set; }

    public object GetValue(string propName)
    {return this.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(this, null)??0;}
    public object GetValue(PropertyInfo propiedad)
    {return propiedad.GetValue(this, null)??0;}
}
```

**Definimos un interfaz** para no depender de la clase:

```
public interface IExcelObj
{
    public object GetValue(string propName);
    public object GetValue(PropertyInfo propiedad);
}
```

Creamos una función para la cabecera genérica para listas de objetos:

```
public string CabeceraCsvExcel(List<Object> ExcelList)
    { string strExcel="";

        PropertyInfo[] propiedades = ExcelList.First().GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetProperties();

        foreach(PropertyInfo propiedad in propiedades)
        {
            strExcel += propiedad.Name;
 
            strExcel+="\t";
        }
        return strExcel;
    }
```

Y otra para la primera fila:

```
public string FilaCsvExcel(List<Object> ExcelList)
    { string strExcel="";
        
        Object fila=ExcelList.First();

        PropertyInfo[] propiedades = fila.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetProperties();

         
            foreach (PropertyInfo propiedad in propiedades)
            {
                strExcel+=((IExcelObj)fila).GetValue(propiedad); 
         
                strExcel+="\t";
            }
  
      
        return strExcel;
    }
```

Al implementar *GetValue* en cada clase controlaremos el formato de salida especifico de cada propiedad(p.e DateTime) cuando sea necesario. La idea final es no tocar este código y que sirva para todos los casos(clases) que se nos puedan dar, trasladando el problema a la implementación de interfaz.

Comment: Francisco, no entiendo muy bien eso de Reflection, como se llamaria al GetPropValue? es decir, que se le enviaria en propName? puedes enviarte un ejemplo de su invocacion? De todas maneras esta salida me funciona: 
ws.Cell(fila, columna).Value = propiedad.GetValue(item);  
Gracias.

Comment: Pues le pasas el nombre de la propiedad

Comment: Ok, justamente lo que queria evitar era pasar los nombres de las propiedades, por que mas adelante puede que envie otra lista a excel, con otros nombres de propiedades.
Al final lo solucione con esto :  
ws.Cell(fila, columna).Value = propiedad.GetValue(item)?.ToString();
Gracias.

Comment: Entiendo, el problema...pero sigues teniendo una dependencia sobre que los datos tienen que ser de tipo typeof(Excel),además que no se sabe si es un objeto o una clase(en tu codigo)

Comment: ok, pero eso ya lo solucione, voy a poner mi solucion, por si alguien mas lo necesite.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente, para que el envio a Excel me sirva para cualquier reporte, y no tener dependencia con type(Excel), mi codigo quedo asi:
Gracias Yussef y Francisco.

```
        public static byte[] ListaXLWaExcel<T>(List<T> lstExcel, string titulo)
    {
        XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook();
        IXLWorksheet ws = workbook.Worksheets.Add("File");

        PropertyInfo[] propiedades = typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().GetProperties();
        int columna = 1;
        foreach (PropertyInfo propiedad in propiedades)
        {
            ws.Cell(1, columna).Value = propiedad.Name;
            columna++;
        }

        int fila = 2;
        foreach (var item in lstExcel)
        {
            columna = 1;
            foreach (PropertyInfo propiedad in propiedades)
            {
                ws.Cell(fila, columna).Value = propiedad.GetValue(item)?.ToString();
                columna++;
            }
            fila++;
        }

        ws.Columns().CellsUsed().SetDataType(XLDataType.Text);
        ws.Columns().AdjustToContents();
        var firstCell = ws.FirstColumn().FirstCellUsed();
        var lastCell = ws.LastColumnUsed().FirstCellUsed();
        var range = ws.Range(firstCell.Address, lastCell.Address);
        range.Style.Alignment.Vertical = XLAlignmentVerticalValues.Center;
        range.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
        range.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.FromHtml("#DAE3EF");
        range.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        range.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.CoolBlack;
        ws.Rows(1, 1).Height = 25;
        ws.Row(1).InsertRowsAbove(2);
        ws.Cell("A2").Value = titulo;
        ws.Cell("A2").Style.Font.Bold = true;
        ws.Cell("A4").SetActive();

        using (MemoryStream Stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            workbook.SaveAs(Stream);
            return Stream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

y la llamada seria de a siguiente manera :

```
var data = Funciones.ListaXLWaExcel(lstExcel, "Documentos Suministro " + codigo);
            string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            return File(data, contentType, "File.xlsx");
```